# Разный текст в QLabel, в заданный интервал времени

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qlabel, qdatetime

Я хочу чтобы менялся текст в `QLabel` с учетом времени (не каждые 15 минут, 
а когда время **`от 6:00 до 9:00 "доброе утро"`**, 
когда **`от 9:00 до 13:00 "хорошей работы"`**).

Причем чтобы от с 6:00 до 9:00 в каждый день были разные надписи( пусть их будет 3 шт.) "доброе утро", "удачного дня", "пусть ваш день будет прекрасным".

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, Qt
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

 
class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        
    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 220)
        
        label = QLabel('<3', self)
        label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter) 
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(40)
        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        label.setFont(font)
        self.show()
     
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте запустить приложение несколько раз в указанное вами время. Если вам что-то не понятно - спросите.

```
import sys
import random
from PyQt5.Qt import *
 
 
class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        
        self._6_9 = [
            "Доброе утро.", 
            "Удачного дня.",
            "Пусть ваш день будет прекрасным.",
        ]
        self._9_13 = [
            "Хорошей работы.",
        ]
        
        hh_mm = QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString('hh:mm')
        #print(f'hh_mm = {hh_mm}') 
        
        if '06:00' <= hh_mm < '09:00':
            self.label.setText(random.choice(self._6_9))
        elif '09:00' <= hh_mm < '13:00':
            self.label.setText(random.choice(self._9_13))
        
        
    def initUI(self):
        self.resize(300, 220)
        
        self.label = QLabel(self)                    
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignTop) 
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccffbd77;")
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        self.label.setFont(font)
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label, stretch=0)
        layout.addWidget(QLabel(
            '<h1 style="color: red;">Hello World.</h1>',  
            alignment=Qt.AlignCenter
            ), stretch=1
        )
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]